# How to use Angular Material table MatSort

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have a `mat-table` I want to add sort functionality to. Can someone tell me why the following isn't working? I get the styled arrows on my column headers but they don't sort the data as expected.

```
<table mat-table matSort [dataSource]="employeeDisplayList" class="mat-elevation-z8 table">

<!-- Employee Name Column -->
<ng-container matColumnDef="employeeName">
  <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Employee Name </th>
  <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element" 
    [ngClass]="{'dependent': element.relationship !== 'Primary'}"> {{element.employeeName}} </td>
</ng-container>

<!-- Relationship Column -->
<ng-container matColumnDef="relationship">
  <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Relationship </th>
  <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"
    [ngClass]="{'dependent': element.relationship !== 'Primary'}"> {{element.relationship}} </td>
</ng-container>

</table>
```

TS:

```
...
import { MatTableModule } from '@angular/material/table';
import { MatSortModule } from '@angular/material/sort';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [EnrollmentComponent, PrepareSubmissionComponent, PlansComponent, EmployeesComponent],
  imports: [
    ...
    MatTableModule,
    MatSortModule
  ]
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to define displayColumns in your component.
Also you have to user MatTableDataSource and put data and sort in it.

Try to add below code in your ts file

```
displayedColumns: string[] = ['employeeName', 'relationship'];
dataSource;

@ViewChild(MatSort, {static: true}) sort: MatSort;

ngOnInit() {
  this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(employeeDisplayList);
  this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
}
```

You also missed below 2 lines in you html.

```
<tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
<tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>
```

Your final html looks like below

```html
<table mat-table matSort [dataSource]="dataSource" class="mat-elevation-z8 table">

  <!-- Employee Name Column -->
  <ng-container matColumnDef="employeeName">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Employee Name </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element" [ngClass]="{'dependent': element.relationship !== 'Primary'}"> {{element.employeeName}} </td>
  </ng-container>

  <!-- Relationship Column -->
  <ng-container matColumnDef="relationship">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Relationship </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element" [ngClass]="{'dependent': element.relationship !== 'Primary'}"> {{element.relationship}} </td>
  </ng-container>

  <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
  <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: you can check this stackblitz for more details: https://stackblitz.com/angular/rnavkdmxbyd?file=src%2Fapp%2Ftable-sorting-example.html

Comment: Thank you for the help, I hadn't converted my datasource to a MatTableDataSource.